# Application not running, android (eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, samsung-mobile

I wanted to run my applications directly through my device. I did the necessary configurations and when I run the application from eclipse it lists the devices to choose from. My device is there and has serial number of 'samsung-gt_s5570..' with target of 2.3.4. When i click OK it says that its installed and done, but how come the application doesn't start on my phone ? is there an extra step to actually run the application or does it just start itself ? Just out of curiosity does mounting the usb having anything to do with it not starting up ?

**UPDATE MANIFEST FILE**

```
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

    </manifest>
```

Comment: Do you have an `Activity` declared as a `launcher` in your `manifest`?

Comment: Does LogCat says anything? Once my app didn't run because I didn't had free space in the device. And it was logged after installation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ALL `Activites` declared in your `manifest` or they won't run. Also, you need one as an entry point to your app or it won't know where to start. Here is an example of mine. Note the `launcher` and `MAIN` `intent filters`

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.some.example.LoginScreen"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale"
        android:label="" >

        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


    </activity>
```

**Note this section in Intent Filters docs below**

> Most applications also have a way to start fresh, without a reference to any particular data. Activities that can initiate applications have filters with "android.intent.action.MAIN" specified as the action. If they are to be represented in the application launcher, they also specify the "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" category:

[Manifest Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

[Intent Filters Launcher](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#ccases)

Comment: So am I to put my current tags nested inside an activity tag ?

Comment: Look at those links I posted. `<manifest><application><activity></activity></application></manifest>` You may have permissions, services, etc...but that is the basic structure. Each `Activity` has its own tag and each of those goes inside the `<application>` tag

Comment: @user1927602 glad I could help. Please accept the answer so it may help others

Answer (score 0):

Post your AndroidManifest.xml, there appear to be no activity with `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` intent-filter. You may also want to add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in order your application appear in the app drawer (launcher).